# floor function identity

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: How to proof? $(n,k\in\mathbb{N})$

$$1=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Are you missing something important in the problem statement? e.g. "... if and only if $k$ divides $n$"?

Comment: This is not correct. Take for example $n=3$ and $k=4$.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\frac nk-1<\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor\le \frac nk$$
and
$$\frac{1-n}k\le-\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor<\frac{1-n}k+1$$
so adding these inequalities  gives
$$\frac1k-1<\underbrace{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor}_{\in\Bbb Z}<\frac1k+1$$
so
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor\in\{0,1\}$$
Notice that the two values are possible. For example: $k=n=1$ gives the value $1$ and $n=2$ and $k=3$ gives the value $0$.

Comment: Dear Smai, do you know any article, book or... in which we can have almost all about the floor function and its properties? (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove what is not true. Plugging in $n<k$ will result in $$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor=0$$